# iOS unit testing with Core Data

Tags: unit-testing, core-data

I'm writing some tests to exercise a CoreData object: `coreobj`

in my test case setup method I have the following initialization:

```
- (void)setUp
{
    [super setUp];
    NSManagedObjectModel *mom = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:[NSBundle allBundles]];
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:mom];
    STAssertTrue([psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSInMemoryStoreType configuration:nil URL:nil options:nil error:NULL] ? YES : NO, @"Should be able to add in-memory store");    
    m_managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    m_managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = psc;

}
```

My first test runs fun, but my second test generates this error in the log file:

```
 Can't merge models with two different entities named 'coreobj'
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [Blog post with grate explanation](http://denizdemir.com/2011/03/24/ios-unit-testing-with-xcode-4-and-core-data/)

It does not solve all the problems do ...

Answer (score 0):

Setup will execute between each test case. It maybe your getting multiple contexts entities that are causing test pollution between each test.